# Complex unique constraints with MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints

Consider the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_val` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_val` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Is it possible to create a constraint that prevents a second record existing in the same table with a `from_val` *or* `to_val` between another record's `from_val` and `to_val`? So, from an empty table the second query should fail with a constraint failure:

```sql
INSERT INTO `demo` (`from_val`, `to_val`) VALUES (1,10),(11,20);
INSERT INTO `demo` (`from_val`, `to_val`) VALUES (5,15);
```

Validating the data on the way in/update is trivial, I was just curious to see whether MySQL could enforce this at a RDBMS level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MySQL does not support (or enforce) any declarative constraint which would raise an exception given the conditions you specify.

The values in the tuple `(5,15)` ("the second query") do not conflict with any values in any of the rows previously inserted into the table... `(1,10),(11,20)`, at least in terms of what is available to declarative constraints in MySQL.

The workaround is to define `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers on the table; those can perform whatever checks you need, and raise an exception.

Comment: +1 for suggesting work around and giving names to the constructs in my head!